How to achieve Generic Return values in a python function
I have a generic function called make_request:
TParams = typing.TypeVar("TParams", bound=typing.Dict[str,str])
TBody = typing.TypeVar("TBody", bound=typing.Dict[str,str])
TEntityDict = typing.TypeVar("TEntityDict")


class SessionFunctionKwargs(typing.Generic[TParams, TBody], typing.TypedDict):
    """
    Dictionary of keyword arguments for the session function.

    Attributes:
        params (TParams | None): The request parameters.
        data (TBody | str): The request body.
        timeout (float): The timeout for the request.
        verify (bool): Whether to verify
    """

    params: typing.NotRequired[TParams | None]
    data: typing.NotRequired[TBody | str | None]
    timeout: float
    verify: bool

    def make_request(
        self,
        fn: typing.Callable[..., requests.models.Response],
        endpoint: str,
        **kwargs: typing.Unpack[SessionFunctionKwargs[TParams, TBody]],
    ) -> TEntityDict:

Since this hasn't got a variable referencing the Generic TEntityDict, mypy will return an error.
It is part of a larger class, but problem is, users of class may need to use the make_request method with different return types each time, so making the class itself generic poses problems.
A thing that worked up until now, was to assign a dummy variable called type: type[TEntityDict] to have the type checker know what to return. This gets harder when a user of the function is Generic and I want to return another generic on top of it e.g.
class User(typing.Generic[TDoc]):
    def retrieve(self) -> TDoc:
        response = self.api_call.make_request(self._endpoint_path, type=TDoc)

This in turn errors with using a type variable in non-type context.
I'm not sure how to tackle this yet.

What are TParams, TBody and TEntityDict? Please [edit] the question to provide more information, making a [mre] that we can copy and replicate the problem ourselves.

@InSync just updated

Please provide an example of how make_request gets used that you assume would make obvious what type TEntityDict should refer to.
